# Labels in CollectionViewCell not showing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have 2 labels and 1 image view in a CollectionViewCell. I can set image in cell but I cant set labels in Cell. CollectionViewCell class:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var weatherIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var degreeLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateTimeLbl: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

how I use it in my view Controller:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.fiveDaysWeather.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell


    if fiveDaysWeather.count > 0{
        let forecast = fiveDaysWeather[indexPath.row]
        let icon = forecast.icon!
        if let url = URL(string: "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(icon).png"){
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                cell.weatherIcon.image = UIImage(data:data)!
            }
        }

        cell.dateTimeLbl?.text = forecast.hour!
        cell.degreeLbl?.text = "\(forecast.tempMax!)°"
    }
    return cell

}
```

I've added a simulator screen and my storyboard screenshot. Thanks for helping.

[Simulator Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sX4M.jpg)

[How I use CollectionViewCell in View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmL8c.png)

Comment: Go to this point in the simulator. Go to Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture view heirachy.  This will give you a lot of info about what is happening with your views.

Comment: I cant see the Cell, just UIImageView. Thank you!

Comment: I fixed it. Really really thank you!!  @AndrewMcKinley

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to register the class. Try this in the viewDidLoad method of the CollectionViewController class.

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell")
```

Also you should check weak variables if they exist. Put a breakpoint on this line of your code and inspect the label/other items:

```
 cell.dateTimeLbl?.text = forecast.hour!
```